# Building and executing C code using azure

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, devops

I am a beginner with CI and trying to wrap my head around how the CI file functions.

I have a simple project with a C file, which prints out some statements.

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main(){    
printf("Hello C Language");    
printf("Hello C Language Again"); 
return 0;   
}
```

I have the CI file as shown below :

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world! lets start your pipeline
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'


- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    script: |
     gcc -o test test.c
      ./test
```

Since I am using the ubuntu VM, I expect gcc to be installed by default. I pass the usual compiling and execution commands of C.

But I face an error [image: Response]

What am I doing wrong here? Any links for me to grasp it better? Many thanks!

---------------UPDATE

I added extra statements as below : [image: Code] and the response is as shown [image: Response]

Comment: Have you tried some logging? You could print out the current path and check if test.c exists. Also you have to watch for spaces. Looks like you have a space too much in the last line. The last two lines have to be in a vertical line.

Comment: @etalon11 : Please see the update

Comment: Are you sure that your command worked?

Comment: Honestly I dont know what has happened.. I can understand that the shell script is created.. echo does not work as well